# Katalon File Upload with Custom Keyword

Tags: java, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I'm using a custom Keyword in Katalon to upload a file to my owncloud server.

```
public class WebUICustomKeyword {
    @Keyword
    def uploadFile(TestObject to, String filePath) {
        WebUI.click(to)
        StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(filePath);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    }
}
```

When calling it in a for-loop just the first iteration is successful. The other stop at uploading in the explorer. (debian 9 stretch)

Surprisingly when calling the keyword twice in a row everything works fine:

```
CustomKeywords.'aCustom.WebUICustomKeyword.uploadFile'(findTestObject('Object Repository/Page_Files - ownCloud/label_Upload'), '/home/timo/Downloads/Ba_MyDigital_School.pdf')    
CustomKeywords.'aCustom.WebUICustomKeyword.uploadFile'(findTestObject('Object Repository/Page_Files - ownCloud/label_Upload'), '/home/timo/Downloads/Ba_MyDigital_School.pdf')

WebUI.click(findTestObject('Page_Files - ownCloud/label_New_Files'))
WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/Page_Files - ownCloud/button_Continue'))
```

Any ideas why? It may be cause of the interrupt?

Comment: Share your code with the for loop and error messages if you have any.

Comment: @MateMrše Well, I just got rid of the problem by adding a thread.sleep() between the keyPress methods.